# the caller was not authenticated by the service -- when using host name in site and call locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis-7

On 1 production server I have a WCF service in the format of:

```
http://[host name]/[OneService.svc]
```

.

When the client app calls it FROM THE SAME SERVER, it throws error of: "The caller was not authenticated by the service...... The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed".

There are a lot of similar topics on Internet. However they all seems not same as my situation. My one is:

1, If client app runs on ANOTHER server within the same domain, or runs on another server within different domain (but these 2 domains are trusted by each other), it works;

2, If client app runs on the SAME server which hosts the WCF service, it throws the error above.

3, HOWEVER, if I change the service URL to

```
http://localhost/[OneService.svc]
```

, then (2) works!

From what I observed in 1/2/3, I am guessing it may not the code or config issue? (Service can be configured to use either http or https.)

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not perfect solution but it does work for me.

I have done regedit ( Please do this at your risk).

You have to create entry for your domain in BackConnectionHostNames key.

http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/05/07/a-quick-guide-to-configuring-the-loopback-check/

Also please give exact authentication error you get if this not work.

Comment: Hi dotnetstep, maybe it's too dangerous to change registry on a production server. Is there any other way I can prove it's that problem?

Comment: We did this on some of my working site that deployed to production. It is upto you that you have to do that or not. When you get authentication error in .net , you also get one error code. If you provide that one than it is easy to find cause for that

Comment: Hi dotnetstep, from WCF traceview, I found 1 'Native Error Code' which is 8009030C

Comment: Hi dotnetstep, we have tried the link you provided, and it proves work. Thanks a lot!