# The caller was not authenticated by the service on same machine

Tags: wcf, iis

I have a WCF service hosted on windows 2016 server in IIS. I also have a windows application to test this WCF service. Service works fine if I run this windows application in any machine except the server where WCF is hosted. Below is my configuration for WCF. I am not able to figure out what is wrong with service.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="TestBehavior" name="">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="" bindingConfiguration="TestSecConfig">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TestSecConfig">

    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TestBehavior">

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

My problems is exactly same what is describe in this question but solution didn't work.
[the caller was not authenticated by the service -- when using host name in site and call locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423068/the-caller-was-not-authenticated-by-the-service-when-using-host-name-in-site)

Answer (score 1):

By default, the credential of the Wshttpbinding security mode is Windows credential, the following configuration is equivalent.

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TestSecConfig">
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

---

```
<wsHttpBinding>
            <binding>
              <security mode="Message">
                <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
              </security>
            </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

So the caller should specify the windows credential when calling this service. the windows credential is server windows account (the host that hosts the WCF service).

```
ServiceReference2.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client();
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "administrator";
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "123456";
```

Based on your requirement, you could also specify the **clientCredentialType="None"**.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding.security?view=netframework-4.8
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.wshttpsecurity.message?view=netframework-4.8#System_ServiceModel_WSHttpSecurity_Message
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thank you for the response. As I mentioned in the question, I am using a windows application to test this service and it works as long as I use windows application in any machine except the server where WCF is hosted. Also I checked code of windows application it is not passing any credential while calling service. I wondering how is it working on other machines but not on server.

Comment: It would use the current login user as a windows credentials by default when we don’t specify the credentials explicitly. Ensure that the server has the specific account and server current login account password is not empty. Besides,try to specify the windows credentials (server account) when calling the service.

Comment: I don't have option to make any code change is client or in service. One thing what I tried is added a existing account inside IIS_USRS group on the server. Then used this account for App pool Identity but still same issue. Am I missing something.

Comment: There may be something amiss with your service domain name conversion system, as you mentioned in the link. Check the connected service endpoint information in the configuration file of your windows application. try to use IP or Localhost to specify the service host address.